# Let A be a symmetric positive definite matrix. Find a matrix B such that $B^2=A$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I believe this question is the same as asking find matrix B to be the square root of the matrix A. $B=\sqrt A$.

Since the problem is not specific I am thinking to solve it in the general case by diagonalizing the matrix and find the eigenvalues and then take the square.

Or, should I just take an example of a matrix A that is symmetric positive semidefinite and find $\sqrt A$ ?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The square root of a matrix is not well-defined. For example, $I_2^2 = I_2$, but $ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)^2 =I_2$ as well

Comment: What is known about $A$? Is $A$ known to be diagonlizable?

Comment: If you just want to find ***one*** example, then diagonalizing $A$ first is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $A$ is symmetric and  real.
Then is it diagonalisable by an orthogonal matrix. That is
$A= U \Lambda U^T$, with $U$ orthogonal and $\Lambda$ diagonal. Since
$A$ is positive semidefinite, all entries of $\Lambda$ are non negative
hence have a square root. Denote the diagonal matrix of square roots by
$\sqrt{\Lambda}$. Let $B = U \sqrt{\Lambda} U^T$, then it is easy to check that
$B^2 = A$.

---

Answer prior to the addition of symmetric, semi-positive definite.

You need some conditions on $A$. Not every matrix is expressible as a square.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Suppose there exists some $B$ such that $B^2 = A$. Then $B$ has only zero eigenvalues. Since $B$ is non-zero, the only possible Jordan normal form for $B$ is $A$, and since $A^2 = 0$, it is impossible.